# Property 'update' does not exist on type 'DocumentReference<DocumentData>' Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to do an update to a Firebase firestore document. However, I am getting the error

> Property 'update' does not exist on type 'DocumentReference'

```
    const Firestore = initializeFirestore(Firebase);

    const vendorsRef = collection(Firestore, '/vendors');
    const q = query(vendorsRef, where("uuid", "==", vendorUuid))
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
    
    querySnapshot.forEach(async (doc) => {
      const delRes = await doc.ref.update({deleted: '06-02-2022'});  // doing soft delete
    });
```

Any suggestions as to why this is?  When I did into the node_modules, the update function appears to be there.  Seems like a typescript issue maybe?  I have also tried doing it the other style I've found where I use

```
Firestore.collection('vendors').doc('something').set(data);
```

But in that style, it tells me that Property 'collection' does not exist on type 'Firestore'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is telling you that there is no method "update" on [v9 DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentreference.md#documentreference_class).  If you look through the linked API doc, you will see that is definitely the case.

It seems you are maybe mixing up the JavaScript v8 and v9 APIs.  [v8 does have update as a method on DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#update) but v9 does not.  If you want to update a document using v9 as you are currently using, you should follow the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data) for that and use the updateDoc function.

```
import { updateDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

await updateDoc(doc.ref, {deleted: '06-02-2022'});
```